# How to capture the screenshot of a specific element rather than entire page using Selenium Webdriver? python

Tags: python

> This question has already been asked and answered only for JavaScript here, but I was  wondering how it could be done in python

I am trying to take some information from a website using Selenium python, but some of the information I want is in images. So im tying to take an image **only of that photo**  I have see people take a normal screenshot and then crop the photo using PIL but I thought there might be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`element.screenshot()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=screenshot#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.screenshot). Below is an example using it to screenshot the logo image of selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def launch_url_elem_screenshot(url):
    ch_service = Service("driver/chromedriver")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ch_service)
    driver.get(url)
    x_path = '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/p/a/img'
    logo = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,x_path)
    logo.screenshot('se_logo.png')
```

Then, when we call this with Selenium doc URL `launch_url_elem_screenshot('https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/')`, the image png file is saved in the current directory.